# Open Whatsapp using a common code ( android and ios) in xamarin form 4.8.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on already developed application on xamarin forms 4.8 (accept that I've no previous experience in xamarin), I need to add functionality to open whatsapp if user clicks the link. the following code was working till API 29, once I deploy  it on android newer version API 30 or above it fails. Same I didn't test it yet on IOS. actually, this form is written in common project library, that's why looking a common code which works on both without writing this form specifically for android and IOS.

```
 string whatsappUri = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ?
            
            $"intent://send?phone={phoneNumber}" :
                    $"whatsapp://send?phone={phoneNumber}";
            Task<bool> taskWhastApp = Launcher.CanOpenAsync(new Uri(whatsappUri));
            Console.WriteLine("iDeclare Whatsapp URL{0} before condition check ", whatsappUri);              

            if (taskWhastApp.Result)
            {
                string ConsoleMsg = "Is Current Task is able to open with full URL {0},\t ,{1}";
                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleMsg, Launcher.CanOpenAsync(new Uri(whatsappUri)).Result, whatsappUri);
                Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(whatsappUri));
            }
```

Comment: The question does not make it clear so I am asking you, what is the issue?